# XML::TWIG to filter the XML in PERL

Tags: perl, xml-twig

I am somehow stuck and banging my head.
I have to delete unwanted TRADES from a huge XML file.

```
<TRADEEXT>
  <TRADE origin = 1,version =1>
     <EVENT externtype ='PROC'/>
     <EVENT externtype ='PROCC'/>
  </TRADE>
  <TRADE origin = 1,version =1>
     <EVENT externtype ='PROCC'/>
  </TRADE>
</TRADEEXT>
```

Now, the second TRADE is having externtype = 'PROCC' inside  node which is not legitimate(legitimate value is 'PROC')

Hence the final output should be

```
<TRADEEXT>
   <TRADE origin = 1,version =1>
      <EVENT externtype ='PROC'/>
      <EVENT externtype ='PROCC'/>
   </TRADE>
<TRADEEXT>
```

which should get pasted to new file. Most important point to be noted here is even though one EVENT is having illegal value, since the other EVENT is having legitimate value, TRADE becomes legitimate.
Hence, at least one EVENT should be legitimate and that will make entire trade legitimate
My code is

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = new XML::Twig( twig_handlers => { TRADE => \&TRADE } );
$twig->parsefile('1513.xml');
$twig->set_pretty_print('indented');
$twig->print_to_file('out.xml');

sub TRADE {
    my ( $twig, $TRADE ) = @_;
    foreach  my $c ($TRADE->children('EVENT')) 
    {
     $c->cut($TRADE) unless
     $c->att('eventtype') eq "PROC"

      ;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it's deleting EVENT tag  instead of TRADE tag.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: sorry...will keep in mind in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know XML::Twig. In XML::LibXML, you'd do

```
for my $bad_trade ('/TRADEEXT/TRADE[ EVENT/@externtype = "PROCC" ]') {
    $bad_trade->parentNode->removeChild($bad_trade);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a `$TRADE->cut` instead of `$c->cut`. However, since your conditional is on `$c`, you may want to do the following instead:

```
sub TRADE {

    my ( $node, $TRADE ) = @_ ;

    $TRADE->cut
      unless grep { $_->att( 'eventtype' ) eq 'PROC' } $TRADE->children( 'EVENT' );
}
```

Comment: Zaid, So nice of you for your invaluable input. Actually FIRST_CHILD will not help because multiple EVENT can be there inside one TRADE...Sorry for missing this in my quetion..Hence, if first EVENT is not satisfying the condition, whereas the second EVENT is satisfying..then also   the trade is legitimate..In short even one of the EVENTS inside any TRADE satisfies teh condition then the TRADE must be selected..

Comment: @vikas : The approach stays the same; just that the conditional needs to be updated to loop over all EVENT nodes and see if any of them have the attribute with the specified value.

Comment: thanks a lot for your efforts. Above snippet of code is copying only those TRADES in a new file which doesn't have 'PROC' at all under any EVENT. Whereas I wanted the opposite. I tried 'ne' instead of 'eq' but to no avail.Please provide your insight

Comment: @vikas : Then change the first snippet from `if` to `unless`

Comment: what if I have to go one level deeper inside EVENT for one more condition. For example inside EVENT...I have <EVENTNARR>. And I have to check attribute value for this also. as an AND condition...In layman's language...eventype attribute of <EVENT> IS PROC and eventcode of <EVENTNARR> must be 1 and this <EVENTNARR> is inside <EVENT>..This is where I got stuck now...please help with some idea